# How to add row / column totals in crosstab?

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab, jaspersoft-studio

In a crosstab, I haven't added the column totals in the end while configuring the crosstab. Now I would want to add it, as it is a new requirement, I am trying, and I am unable to find it

How do I go about this? Should I add a new column group, if yes, I have tried, and it appears after every column group in the output.

How do I add it so as to make it appear in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Each group that you have in your crosstab can have a total cell, you need to find the correct group (the group you like to add the total cell),

1. Click the group in the outline.
2. In Properties (Cell tab), as Total Position (None, Start, End), select Start (before data) or End (after data) to add the total cell.

[image: Screen shot]

You should automatically see the total cell added under the "fakeGroup" node, if not close report and reopen.